# What to do when a third suited card appears on the river

Tags: texas-hold-em, cash-game, drawing

9 player cash game. Blinds 1c/2c. I am UTG with K:hearts: K:diamonds: I raise to 8c. Everyone folds to the button who calls. SB and BB fold. The pot is 19c. Flop comes 9:spades: 2:spades: K:clubs:. The button is sort of a calling station (calls pot-sized bets with gutshot draws!). I bet 16c. He calls. Turn is 4:diamonds:. I bet 48c into a 51c pot. He calls again! The pot is now $1.47. River comes Q:spades:

- Should I bet? If I don't bet, he might try to bluff me. And then I wouldn't know whether to call. If I should bet, how much should I bet. (my remaining stack is around $4, his is around $3)
- I did bet 75c. Perhaps he hit his draw or sensed weakness, he raised to $2. Should I call?

Generally, when you're out of position and feel that your opponent wrongly calls you with a draw, should you continue betting when one of the possible draws completes?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your impressions of your opponent, if he's tight he wouldn't ever call your bets on the flop and turn with only a draw. In that case bet because he has something and he's willing to call with what he has and you have him beat. If he's a loose player then he could have the flush. If you check he'll bet on the river 9 times out of ten. You have to ask yourself what's the chance he's bluffing. Since you know he's loose then there's a good chance he's bluffing and you have to call. So bottom line, if your opponent is tight bet the river for value, if he's loose, check call.

Answer (score 0):

Its a difficult spot as you have a reasonably strong hand, but it doesnt beat a flush.

You want to be able to get away from it if possible. So I would put a bet in of 1/3 pot. When he 3-bets if its a shove I fold. If its not a shove, I might be tempted to call if you are saying he's a calling station, he could be bluffing on the river. I think a call is probably the right choice.